# Finding Laurent and Taylor series

Tags: taylor-expansion, laurent-series

I need to find both a Laurent and a Taylor expansion.

$$f(z)=\frac{z}{(z-1)(z-2)} = \frac{-1}{(z-1)}+\frac{2}{(z-2)}$$

If I choose $z_0=0$

$$f(z)=\frac{1}{(1 + z)} - \frac{4}{\left(1 - \frac{z}{4}\right)}$$

$$f(z)=\sum_{n}^{\infty}(-1)^n{z^n} - 4\sum_{n}^{\infty}(\frac{z}{4})^n$$

Which is a Taylor series.

---

What value of $z_0$ would you pick for a Laurent series?

Comment: You lost me on your second step. Isn't it $f(z)=\dfrac{1}{1-z}-\dfrac{1}{1-\tfrac{z}{2}}$?

Comment: For Laurent series expansion see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1180609/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is sufficient to consider a Laurent expansion around $z=0$. Depending  on the region which you then choose you obtain a principal part of a Laurent expansion respectively an expansion as Taylor series.

> The function
>
> \begin{align*}
>  f(z)&= \frac{-1}{z-1}+\frac{2}{z-2}\\
> \end{align*}
>    has two simple poles at $1$ and $2$.
>
> We look at the poles $1$ and $2$ and see they determine *three* regions.
>
> \begin{align*}
>  |z|<1,\qquad\quad
>  1<|z|<2,\qquad\quad
>  2<|z|
>  \end{align*}
>
> - The first region $ |z|<1$ is a disc with center $0$, radius $1$ and the pole $1$ at the boundary of the disc. In the *interior* of this disc all two fractions with poles $1$ and $2$  admit a representation as *Taylor series* at $z=0$.
> - The second region $1<|z|<2$ is the annulus with center $0$, inner radius $1$ and outer radius $2$. Here we have a representation of the fraction with pole $1$ as principal part of a Laurent series at $z=0$, while the fraction with pole at $2$ admits a representation as power series.
> - The third region $|z|>2$ containing all points outside the disc with center $0$ and radius $2$ admits for all fractions a representation as principal part of a Laurent series at $z=0$.

A Tayor series expansion of $\frac{1}{z+a}$ at $z=0$ is
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{z+a}&=\frac{1}{a}\cdot\frac{1}{1+\frac{z}{a}}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{a^{n+1}}(-z)^n
\end{align*}
The principal part of $\frac{1}{z+a}$ at $z=0$ is
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{z+a}&=\frac{1}{z}\cdot\frac{1}{1+\frac{a}{z}}=\frac{1}{z}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{a^n}{(-z)^n}
=-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{a^n}{(-z)^{n+1}}\\
&=-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{a^{n-1}}{(-z)^n}
\end{align*}

Comment: At last I understand :)

Comment: @paranoidhominid: Good to see the answer is useful! :-)